# Exporting sheet template to PDF generates Runtime Error 5: Invalid Procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have created a macro to export the sheet template to PDF:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Survey Report.pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
  :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

I tried it other ways but it makes no difference in error.

Links already tried:

1. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/608810-printing-multiple-worksheets-pdf-2.html
2. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/385749-exportasfixedformat-error.html
3. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument/574c2c8f-7f2c-4644-9373-bbc14c8d3fd7?msgId=4dbee3f3-ad28-4427-a50b-a3904b09ec1e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your actual code works for me. However try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Survey Report.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

**Note**:

1. Also hope `Sheet2` has something in it to print else a blank sheet will give you the error.
2. If you want to print the sheet from the workbook where you are running the code then you might want to change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` and try again...

Comment: I have installed Microsoft SaveAsPdf setup on my system & code started working for me too. I don't know if this is the real solution of this problem, as it makes mandatory for each client system using this macro to have this software setup installed. Thanks.

Comment: This is cool (+1)! I came to realize that hidden and very hidden sheets also throw run-time error 5 (invalid procedure call or argument) when `ExportAsFixedFormat` is called on them.

Answer (score 4):

I also got this error and tried doing it manually to work out the problem.

Turns out that you can't save as PDF when the filename (including path) is longer than 218 characters.

Comment: This. I have heard reports of it being a 255 character limit ... I have hit this 218 limit today. 
Excel may as well just make error messages like "Error: Something error-ed".

Answer (score 2):

You also must have Excel's free [Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7) installed.

Answer (score 1):

if you have adobe printer installed then just use below code to get a pdf

```
sub Sample()
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Printout
End Sub
```