# VBA Run-time error '5' invalid procedure call or argument presenting a problem on certain machines when creating a .pdf with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I've created an ActiveX button in Excel that should create a PDF document on the users desktop:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'file name as a cell value
Dim flenm As Range
'path to the users desktop
Dim desktoppath As String

Set flenm = Sheet1.Range("D21")
desktoppath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")


' pdf creation
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=desktoppath & "\" & _
flenm & ".pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True


' confirmation
MsgBox ("The PDF should be saved on your desktop as '" & flenm & ".pdf'." & vbNewLine _
& " If you have issues with this, please let me know." & vbNewLine _
& " Save Location: " & desktoppath)
End Sub
```

It works fine on my computer (Windows 7, Excel 2007, non-admin) and on one of my colleagues computer (Windows 10, Excel 2016, admin), but other than that on all the other machines I've tested (all Windows 7, Excel 2007, non-admin), it throws a Run-time error '5': invalid procedure.

I can't work out what the issue is. Could it be something to do with having different PDF software, or something to do with permissions (although we've tried setting them all to be exactly the same), or just an error with the code?

At any rate if anyone has any idea I would love to hear. If more information is required, please just ask.

Comment: Help us to help you; **on which line of code does the macro fail ??**

Comment: Does this help?  [Runttime error 5 invalid procedure call or argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053873/runtime-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument).  In fact there are a few questions answered on SO on this very topic if you search...

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Ahh, it's line 9; 'ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=desktoppath & "\" & _
flenm & ".pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True'

Comment: @Ian I have checked out most of the answers on here but none of them seem to work, and I've certainly not seen one regarding it not working on different machines. However, if you can see a place on SO where it's already been answered it would be helpful! 

Just tried the code from the answer you suggested but it still threw the same error sadly.

Comment: Does it work when you turn open after publish into false?

Comment: If you have further information, including what you've tried, you should make sure that's added to the question so other new readers can find it easily (without having to trawl through comments) ;)  On the problem, one answer suggested that the path was too long - in your case this could affect different machines...

Comment: Also, do the desktop path's get printed correctly into your messageboxes?

Comment: @Luuklag the 'open after publish' change doesn't work sadly, and the path is correct, even on others machines.

Comment: @Ian Good shout, I'll update the answer! I don't think it's an issue with the path being too long (I did find that in another question) because the admin username is the longest out of all of them and it worked in that instance. Unless there would be something else that effects the length of the path I'm not sure...

Comment: please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question accordingly

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the question. Like OP said, the code works fine for some computers but not for others, how much more explanation would you require. BTW the code works fine for me as well. Before the export line use `msgbox desktoppath & "\" & flenm & ".pdf"`, make sure there is no punctuation in the string. Also there may be a different way to get the dektop addres such as `fileNm = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"`

Comment: You are saying that the error is thrown with Excel 2007, right? Is it possible that you need for this version to install a [plugin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7) being able to export to PDF. Also said int [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053873/runtime-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument) @Ian provided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Runtime Error : 5, Invalid Procedure call or argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053873/runtime-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument)

Comment: @Storax- OP wants to save the workbook to the users desktop also xl 2007 started using saveas pdf

Comment: @Davesexcel: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean maybe because of my English. My understanding is that the OP wants to export the Activesheet as PDF and that this is not working on several computers with Excel 2007. So, my guess is that on these computers the _2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS_ plugin is missing.

Comment: I can't actually edit the question; it won't allow me to for some reason.

Comment: @Storax that sounds like a likely issue - I will test that and let you know

Comment: Also something to think about, if the computers do not have any print driver installed, the saveas pdf will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not allowed to answer my own question for some reason (I wasn't allowed to edit my answer either).

I have found the answer based on suggestions given. The problem was the lack of this;

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7

on the end users machines. We have tested it now and it works fine.