# I am getting "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel file, there is a button. When I click the button, the data will be saved in another sheet and I will preview in the pdf file. When I run the code in another system it's not working. It's throwing errors. *Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument*. How to solve this?

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "Q-" & Range("J5").Value, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: Have you checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053873/exporting-sheet-template-to-pdf-generates-runtime-error-5-invalid-procedure-cal) yet? They mention sheets being hidden/filenames being too long being an issue.

Comment: What is `Range("J5").Value` when it fails?

Comment: it is a 2-digit number. J5 is 12 (filename will be Q-12)

Comment: Add `MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address(1, 1, , 1) & vbLf & WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.UsedRange)` before the line and post the result

Comment: `Filename:= "Q-" & Range("J5").Value & ".pdf" `  ?